# How to override a method of a class where the method itself is defined in its parent class, and only called in the current class?

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, preference

I would like to extend the `OrderSender` class, located at `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\` and then override the method `prepareTemplate($order)`, this method is actually defined in the `Sender` class which is located at `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\` and only called at `OrderSender` class as `parent::prepareTemplate($order);` because the `OrderSender` class extends `Sender`, class.

Now how can I override the `prepareTemplate($order)` method in the `OrderSender` class which is not defined here but just called?

Note: I don't want to extend its parent class (`Sender` ) and override the method.

Answer (score 0):

You only have two choices

- 1 : You extend the parent class Sender and override there, but it doesn't seem to suits you
- 2 : You override the method where the prepareTemplate is called and instead of calling prepareTemplate, you call a custom method that you writte in your extend class. So technically speaking, it won't be an extend of prepareTemplate, just a new method that will do mostly the same thing but with your custom code